# Mysql me obliga a rellenar campos not null de repente [mysql mode strict]

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

PHP PDO o MYSQL me está obligando, de un día para otro, a guardar campos `not null` de una tabla, antes, si era un entero, mysql automáticamente le ponía un `0`.

Me explico.

Tengo esta tabla: clientes

```
id int auto incremental not null
nombre text not null
apellidos text not null
id_usuario int not null
```

Y esta mi consulta:

```
INSERT INTO clientes(nombre, apellidos) VALUES(:nombre, :apellidos)
```

Esta consulta hace 1 día, sin cambiar el código, me funcionaba bien, llenaba los campos `nombre` y `apellidos`, automáticamente se rellenaba el campo `id` auto incrementándose y el campo `id_usuario` le ponía un 0 automáticamente mysql. Y no daba ningún error.

Hoy, ya no funciona, me da el siguiente error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'id_usuario' doesn't have a default value.
```

También me está pasando con las cadenas vacías, antes si le pasaba una cadena vacía a un campo `int`, este automáticamente lo interpretaba como nada y le ponía el valor `0`. Ahora da el error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: ''
```

Creo que Mysql se ha vuelto restrictivo de un día para otro, no se si se ha actualizado solo o que ha pasado... ¿existe alguna manera de cambiar esto para que este como antes?

EDITO: Viendo el log en Ubuntu, hoy a las 6 am se ha actualizado Mysql y a pasado de la versión 5.7.21 a la 5.7.22. Seguro que tiene algo que ver.

Saludos y gracias.

Comment: pero se supone que si esta en not null, deberia poner obligadamente algo , porque la propiedad del campo así lo dicta, si quieres que no te obligue ponle null al campo

Comment: Si pero antes mysql no me daba ningún error... Llevo meses usandolo de esta manera y no me daba ningún error y de un día para otro se ha colapsado toda la página por esto. Algo ha cambiado para que sea restrictivo.

Comment: coloca valor por defecto a esos campos, si usas phpmyadmin ve a la modificación dle campo y en el apartado 'predeterminado' coloca la opción personalizado y ahí rellena con el valor que desees que se rellene.

Comment: podrias usar algo asi para establecer null ALTER TABLE tabla CHANGE columna type DEFAULT NULL

Comment: Al parecer se ha actualizado mysql y ha pasado de la versión 5.7.21 a 5.7.22, seguro tiene algo que ver.

Comment: Las actualizaciones automáticas hacen muchísimo daño @Salpicaduras Esperemos que puedas volver a la versión anterior facilmente.

Comment: No creo que sea malo. Por supuesto que resulta catastrófico si antes no tenías ningún control y se lo delegabas al SGBD, pero desde el principio debes asegurarte de la integridad de la información, debes buscar un control explícito para todos estos casos. Sé que, por ejemplo, SQL Server dejaba ejecutar las sentencias "así como así", pero en la última versión requiere terminar cada sentencia con su `;` respectivo.

Comment: No creo que sea algo malo lo que ha hecho MySQL en su nueva actualización, ha venido más bien a corregir irregularidades en tu base de datos. Esto se resuelve muy fácil, estableciendo un valor por defecto  en el caso de esos campos y listo, problema resuelto. En ningún caso reviertas la actualización, pues por lo general las actualizaciones corrigen muchos fallos, y en algunos casos corrigen errores críticos, bugs, agujeros de seguridad, etc, etc.

Comment: @A.Cedano gracias a todos, he hecho eso, algunos campos los he puesto como nulos, otros con opción predeterminada, y el problema de la cadena vacía en un entero, una validación para pasarle un 0. Lo que hacía antes MySql ahora lo hago manual. Seguiré revisando todo el codigo a ver si encuentro más de esto. Intente hacer un downgrade a la versión 5.7.11 disponible en los paquetes de Ubuntu pero no se realizaba completamente. Asi que opte por la solucion anteriormente comentada. Saludos y gracias.

Comment: Has optado por la mejor solución. Saludos.

Comment: Yo tengo el mismo problema, pero.... mysql..... está en el hosting que tengo contratado, por lo que ¿Hay alguna manera de modificarlo?. Quizás modificar algo en phpmyadmin??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Al parecer con la actualización de MySQL se activaron algunos atributos que hacían más restrictivo MYSQL.

Esto es modificable en el archivo my.cnf de MYSQL.

Puedes descubrir que parametros tiene el SQL_MODE de tu MYSQL con el comando:

```
SELECT @@sql_mode;
```

Si quieres modificar esto tienes que irte a:

```
/etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

Y añadir la sentencia debajo de [mysqld]:

```
sql-mode=""
```

Dentro de la comillas puedes poner los parámetros que quieras o dejarlo vacío, según tus necesidades.

Luego reinicias mysql y listo.

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

Saludos y gracias por todo.